# ¿Como puedo volver a entrar al usuario?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Buen dia para todos.
Compañeros tengo el sistema operativo Red hat enterprise linux, sin querer sali del usuario por terminal y quedo en (bash-4.2).
Me podrian ayudar a como puedo hacer para volver entrar al usuario.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy confusa y no se adapta al sitio, te recomiendo que te pases por [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y reformules tu pregunta en base a ello para que no sea cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas en consola como usuario regular puedes cambiarte invocando **login**

```
shell$ login pedro
Password:

shellDePedro$
shellDePedro$ exit

shell$
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** puede que existan limitaciones con el comando login y
>   su/sudo, esto ya depende como se crean los usuarios y sus privilegios
>   en /etc/group.